# Understanding how to map events in xaml

Tags: xaml, events, binding

I don't know C# events very well so I have difficulties in understanding some code [I found in internet](http://www.yumasoft.com/node/47)

Inside the code behind of a view file there is the following method:

```
public void SavingMesBoxClosedHandler(object sender, object args)
```

The **DisplayMessageBox** class is derived form FrameworkElement and defines the following event:

```
    public delegate void MessageBoxClosedHandler(object sender, object args);
    public event MessageBoxClosedHandler DialogClosed;
```

Inside the xaml of the view:

```
 <DisplayMessageBoxDemo:DisplayMessageBox 
       // some dependency properties here
        DialogClosed="SavingMesBoxClosedHandler"/>
```

I thought I could use only dependency properties, while DialogClosed is an event.
Which is the magic to map a method of the view to an event in **DisplayMessageBox** class using only its name ?

Why don't I have to use a binding ?

Is there an easy way to assign a viewmodel method as the event handler of DialogClose ? 
May be I didn't use the correct terms in my last question. To put in other words I want to call a method inside my viewmodel, not in the view as in the example I reported above.

Comment: You should use the `EventHandler<T>` delegate instead of creating your own.

Comment: In WPF, you should use [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) instead.

Comment: Can you add a code sample which has the same behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use only dependency properties in XAML. You can use normal properties just as well. Dependency properties are a necessity when you use DataBinding, as you point out. In the case you mention there seems to be no need to use DataBinding because you will not use different handlers depending on your DataContext. If you want to stick to the MVVM pattern and keep the event handling logic in your view model, you can use EventTrigger: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/using-eventtrigger-in-xaml-for-mvvm-no.html